# Что быстрее: .get() или in?

Tags: python, dict

Предположим, есть словарь, и надо узнать, есть ли там ключ. Что быстрее работает?

```
search_key in sample_dict
```

или

```
sample_dict.get(search_key)
```

Comment: Не нужно заниматься микрооптимизациями. Используйте то что подходит семантически (по смыслу) - в данном случае это in.

Comment: `in` работает чуть быстрее. Но если вам потом может понадобиться и значение, то лучше использовать `get`, запоминая его результат в переменную.

Comment: get не для проверки наличия ключа. Он возвращает значение по ключу или None, если ключа нет, но он также возвращает None, если ключ есть, и значение - None.

Comment: @insolor Если значений `None` в словаре заведомо нет, то это можно использовать

Comment: Можно, но не нужно

Comment: Если в словаре лежит `None` или `False`, то `.get` сработает не так, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: @insolor Ну, если прям критичное по времени приложение, то два раза хэш от ключа считать может быть хуже, чем один раз. )  Так то по чистоте кода я согласен.

Comment: ок, спасибо, не ожидал, что "in" быстрее. Думал просто что "in" перебирает и его сложность O(N), а сложность get О(1). Понял, спасибо. Неожиданный момент)

Comment: Для каждого (стандартного) контейнера in работает так же как и условный get (получение значения), только само значение не получает. Для словаря - просто проверяется наличие ключа, а не перебираются ключи.

Comment: @Алексей Читайте доки https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity там всё есть. "Худший случай" - это когда у ключей сплошные коллизии хэша и нужен перебор всех элементов. Но это тоже будет одинаково работать для `in` и `get`.